# Averaging three raster images (of same month obtained from three data centres) for approx 150 months using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, batch

How do I average the three raster images obtained from three data centre for each month of 15 years approx?

I tried to do it using Graphical Model in QGIS but it shows an error.

**Error Log in QGIS**

```
Processing algorithm 1/1…
Algorithm GRACE Combined Average starting…
Input parameters:
{'CSRLayer': 'G:/My '
'Drive/My_Data/ASHISH-Unsorted/PhD/Literature/Proposal/River '
'Basin/Data/GRACE/CSR/GRD-3_2003001-2003031_GRAC_UTCSR_BA01_0600_LND_v03.tif',
'GFZLayer': 'G:/My '
'Drive/My_Data/ASHISH-Unsorted/PhD/Literature/Proposal/River '
'Basin/Data/GRACE/GFZ/GRD-3_2003001-2003031_GRAC_GFZOP_BA01_0600_LND_v03.tif',
'JPLLayer': 'G:/My '
'Drive/My_Data/ASHISH-Unsorted/PhD/Literature/Proposal/River '
'Basin/Data/GRACE/JPL/GRD-3_2003001-2003031_GRAC_JPLEM_BA01_0600_LND_v03.tif',
'qgis:rastercalculator_1:GRACE Combined Average': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':G:/My Drive/My_Data/ASHISH-Unsorted/PhD/Literature/Proposal/River Basin/Data/GRACE/Combined_Average/CA_GRD-3_2003001-2003031_GRAC_JPLEM_BA01_0600_LND_v03.tif, 'createOptions': {}}>}

An error occurred while performing the calculation
Error encountered while running Raster calculator
Algorithm GRACE Combined Average failed…
Execution failed after 0.64 seconds
Batch execution completed in 0.74 seconds
1 executions failed. See log for further details.
```

Comment: Hello, in QGIS I recommend you to try first with the raster calculator, (@raster1+@raster2+@raster3)/3. In order to prevent problems with the images.
If the images have similar dimensions and are aligned you should do it without any problem. Next, you could do a batch processing, using the process toolbox. In Raster Analisys>Raster Calculator

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you wish to ask the same thing about ArcGIS Desktop then please do that in a separate question and be sure to specify whether you are using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap in your testing.